# Problem on continuity based on functional relation

Tags: continuity

Given that  $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies

$2f^3(x)-3=2x-3f(x)$ , $x\in \mathbb{R}$, show that  $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

How can we handle this problem?

Comment: you can solve this equation for $f(x)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sounds like a good idea... until having a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2y%5E3-3-2x-3y%3D0  :P

Comment: yes i saw this result, it is a polynomial of degree three

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I saw some hideous cube roots and fractions of cube roots, but maybe a simplification will bring the polynomial you evoke ... Anyway, don't you approve my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $$F(x):=2f^3(x)+3f(x)$$
then
$$F(x)=3+2x$$
hence $F$ is continuous. Now let us define $$ G(y):= 2y^3 + 3y $$
then, since $G'(y)=6y^2+3>0\ $, (plus computing the limits in $\pm\infty$, $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a diffeomorphism (i.e. $t\mapsto G^{-1}$ exists and is continuous).

We have 
$$ F=G\circ f$$
so 
$$ f=G^{-1}\circ F$$
hence $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The solution  of @Netchaiev is short and smart. I managed to get to  a lengthy alternative below:

For $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $2f^3(x_0)=2x_0-3f(x_0)+3$

Subtract  the latter  from  the given $2f^3(x)=2x-3f(x)+3$ to take

$2(f^3(x)-f^3(x_0)) +3(f(x)-f(x_0))= 2(x-x_0)$

or

$2(f(x)-f(x_0))(f^2(x)+f(x)f(x_0)+f^2(x_0))+3(f(x)-f(x_0))=2(x-x_0)$

or

$(f(x)-f(x_0))(2f^2(x)+2f(x)f(x_0)+2f^2(x_0)+2+1)=2(x-x_0)$

Let $A(x) = 2f^2(x)+2f(x)f(x_0)+2f^2(x_0)+2$

the above is quadratic with respect to $f(x)$ with discriminant

$\Delta = (2f(x))^2-4\cdot2\cdot(2f^2(x)+2)=4f^2(x)-8\cdot2\cdot f^2(x)-16= -12f^2(x)-16<0$

thus $A(x)>0, \forall x$ and

$(f(x)-f(x_0))(A(x)+1)=2(x-x_0)$. Then

$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|=\frac{\left|2(x-x_0)\right|}{A(x)+1}\leq \left|2(x-x_0)\right|$, since $A(x)+1>1$

or

$-\left|2(x-x_0)\right| \leq f(x)-f(x_0) \leq \left|2(x-x_0)\right|$

We have that $\lim_{x \to x_0} 2(x-x_0) = 0$

then from the squeeze theorem it follows that $\lim_{x \to x_0} (f(x)-f(x_0)) = 0$, thus $f(x)$ is continuous

Comment: At first I wanted to do the same : with my notation computing $F(x)-F(x_0)$ and factorizing by $(f(y)-f(y_0))$, but it appears we may want to have a lower bound for $f$ which gives the will to express $f$ in term of $F$ to obtained that ; but finally, when you do that you obtain $G$ and then becomes finally direct.